# Thin and sinatra - how to stop/restart? No thin.pid

Tags: sinatra, thin

I'm using thin as the server for my Sinatra app. It is started thusly:

```
thin -C config/environment.yml -R config/config.ru start
```

Where `environment.yml` has thin stuff and `config.ru` has general stuff you'd find in a rackup file.

I would like to be able to daemonize (easy enough with thin's config file) and stop and restart this much like one does with apache/tomcat/etc.

When I try `thin stop` or restart or various other things, I get:

`Can't stop process, no PID found in tmp/pids/thin.pid`

Indeed, there is no such file. I have tried specifying a pid file and location (ex. `/tmp/thin.pid`, to be easy) in the thin configuration yml to various different places. All this does is change the location of the directory in the `"no PID found in"` message, still no pid file is created.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your app really running? Do you get thin with `ps ax | grep thin`?

Comment: Yes, the app is running, I get it with ps and I can connect to it via the browser/curl/what have you. I run it currently in a `screen` and, when I want to restart, simply `screen -r`, `ctrl+c`, and restart manually. I would like to do better.

Comment: Have you tried `thin -C config/environment.yml stop`?

Comment: I have, and I get that message. The only difference between `thin stop` and `thin -C whatever.yml stop` is the location of the directory where it's meant to be looking for pids. With the yaml file specified, it will look in the directory specified by the `pid:` option in that file. But either way, no pid file is ever written anywhere, as far as I can tell, by thin. I've tried adjusting the location, permissions, etc. No luck.

Comment: from your question I guess you have daemonize option in you config file. But how about specifying `--daemonize` switch too?

Comment: I swear it wasn't working before, but now it is. I had tried both with and without daemonize set to true. Now it works, only when daemonize is true. That means I need to get my logging in order quicker than I was going to, but that's fine. Submit it as an answer and I'll accept. Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pid will be created when thin is daemonized, so double-check your config for `daemonize: true` option. Considering that it's yaml, whitespace can make things go wrong. Alternatively specify `--daemonize` switch.

If location of your pid file is non-default, you should also specify config file when issuing stop:

```
thin -C config/environment.yml stop
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this should be `daemonize: true` in the config file (i.e. no "d")